# R Kaplan Meier curve -divide curves by gender and risk factor

Tags: r

I'd like to create a Kaplan meier curve which looks similar to the Kaplan Meier curve of this [link (Researchgate)](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Kaplan-Meier-estimates-by-groups-of-sex-within-treatment-strata-in-matched-cohort_fig3_311940636) 
[image: Kaplan meier]

I got 2 seperate variables: 1. gender (1=male, 2 = female)  2. risk factor (1=present 0= not present)
The risk groups of the Kaplan meier curve should be divided by sex and a second riskfactor.

```
Curve 1 : Male + Risk factor present
Curve 2 : Male + No risk factor
Curve 3: Female + risk factor present
Curve 4: Female+ No risk factor
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: 
http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/survminer-r-package-survival-data-analysis-and-visualization#survival-curves-with-multiple-groups

```
# Fit (complexe) survival curves
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
require("survival")
fit2 <- survfit( Surv(time, status) ~ gender + risk factor,
   data = colon )
# Visualize
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# Visualize: add p-value, chang y limits
# change color using brewer palette
ggsurvplot(fit2, pval = TRUE, 
       break.time.by = 800,
       risk.table = TRUE,
       risk.table.height = 0.5#Useful when you have multiple groups
       )
```